# check multiple values in checkedlistbox

Tags: c#

i am having a checkedlistbox, wherein i have 12 months .. i want to check whether the selected months fee is already paid or not from the database.

Also if 1 months fee is paid and other which i have selected are not paid , then it should validate and show that this month is paid and others should go in datagrid for receipt.

Im done with 1 month selected but when i select multiple months then im getting no value from Database Against This Query

sql query is

```
select Status from dbo.table where Month='Jan', 'Feb' ,'March'
```

How to get one Column Value in Three Rows?

Answer (score 0):

The question is not very clear.

If you want to get the selected months from the check list box and then get status of the selected months u can do this :-

```
        string months = String.Empty;

        foreach (var item in checkedListBox1.CheckedItems)
        {
            months += "months = '"+item.ToString()+"' or ";
        }
        months = months.Substring(0, months.Length - 4);
```

now make your query string by this :-

```
string SelectQuery = "select Status from dbo.table where " + months;
```

if u have the list of months and according to that that if u want to select the corresponding checkboxes u can do this (assuming u have values of months in "January, March, April" format);

```
string month = "January,March,December";
foreach (string item in month.Split(','))
        {

            checkedListBox1.SetItemChecked(checkedListBox1.Items.IndexOf(item),true);
        }
```

Comment: after i get the selected months, i want to check with its status whether it is paid or not from database and if paid then messagebox.show() else ...
what should i write in the if condition to check value from database ..

Comment: sorry if u dint unstan my question..
i have checkedlistbox , ive added 12 months in the list.. now when i select multiple months i want to check whether any month is having value 'paid' in the database... if any of it has den messagebox.show "selected month is already paid" and others whose are not should go in datagridview..
i have ytable with columns Monthname and Status ..

Comment: Change string SelectQuery = "select * from dbo.table where " + months; This query will give you the datatable containing the status and selected Months. Now iterate each row of datatable using foreach loop and display messagebox or datagridrow as required...Hope your problem is now resolved